Backup active storage document to track the changes
#<UserDocument:0x00007dd24a338ae8                                       
 id: 697,                                                               
 file: nil,                                                             
 user_id: 57,                                                           
 document_type_id: 18,                                                  
 created_at: Mon, 28 Oct 2024 11:16:39.060267000 IST +05:30,            
 updated_at: Mon, 28 Oct 2024 11:16:39.060267000 IST +05:30,            
 verified: false,                                                       
 remark: nil,                                                           
 backup_file: nil> 

I want best utilization of storage in application,
I am using active storage
In UserDocument model if file (.pdf) is updating then give its backup before destroying previous version in the backup file paramter with 1) compressing the file size of backup doc only
2) keep the backup file for only 5 days the remove and clear space
override the purge in active storage

Not clear what you are trying to accomplish -- you've splattered a number of wants around.
